# MariaDB suddenly denies remote connections that were working

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I'm having this strange problem and I wanted to know if anyone had it.

My site's architecture consists in two servers: one running the web-application (Python/Django) and the other one running MariaDB.

The site has been running over a year now, and it was pretty stable but now I'm having this strange issue.

Last week randomly, Django starts crashing because it can't connect to the server. I receive emails with this error log:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'x.x.x.x' (using password: YES)")
```

For me it was pretty obvious that this was a database problem, so the first thing I did was to restart the server running MariaDB. After that, the web-app could connect to the server and everything was up and running ok.

The strange thing is that the user is in the table with the correct IP, the site was running with the same credentials almost a year and after the reset, it started working again.

Two days after that and yesterday it happened again and I "fixed it" the same way both times.

The error logs are empty, and I started logging all the queries. I didn't find anything strange in the last query executed before denying access to the web-app.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem... Any help is very welcomed!

The database is not small (10GB), can it be related?

Thanks!!

Comment: It could be a number of reason. From your description i guess that you are hitting a

max_connections 

or 

max_user_connections

Check database server error log and if that is the case increase both values on my.cnf file.

Answer (score 0):

He just said there were no errors logged.

I have a similar circumstance, I have a replication group set up in Azure and any time one of the mariadb services is restarted, all of a sudden the replication user gets 'access denied' on the slave connected to it. I have to stop the slave, set all slave threads to zero, start the slave, stop it again, set the slave threads to what I had them set to before, start the slave, and everything works again. Just stopping and starting the slave does not work. I was completely resetting replication on the slave via a change master command, that just gets burdensome after a while.

It seems like some odd issue when the services starts and DNS, but I am not certain. Nor have I tracked it down yet.

This is just a hack, but try it maybe it will work for you (I created a BASH script to do it, until I track the problem down). Also, make sure you have everything set up to use IP addresses, not hostnames (replication, CNF settings, wherever you would use them). Try setting skip_name_resolve differently also.

For the record, I use Ansible, the deployment is the same as I've used in GCE and on bare metal many times before. No reason it should act differently.